# How can I kill a enemy upon jumping on him in a 2d platformer?

Tags: game-development, godot

I was trying to implement a kill feature where player can jump on top of enemies and enemy will die, I first calculated the y co-ordinate of the player and enemy.After that using if statement i checked if player's y co-ordinate<enemies y co-ordinate then I make the player die. But problem comes when run towards the player it also makes the enemy die.

Here is my sample code:

```
if collision.collider.is_in_group('enemy'):
    var player_feet = (position + $CollisionShape2D.shape.extents).y
    print(player_feet)
    if player_feet < collision.collider.position.y:
        print(player_feet)
        print(collision.collider.position.y)
        collision.collider.take_damage()
        velocity.y = -200
    else:
        hurt()
```

And here is my player and enemy sprite position

- [Player's sprite position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwsf7.png)
- [Enemy's sprite position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1mWq.png)

Is there any other approach to solve this problem or what should I change in my code?

Comment: Look into `KinematicCollision2D`'s function `get_normal()`. The normal of the collision is the direction the face of the shape is pointing. So if your enemy was a square and you landed on top, the normal would point `Vector2.UP`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the vertical velocity `velocity.y`. If the player moving downwards `velocity.y > 0` then it could have fallen on the enemy. Otherwise not.

*Actually, you might want to use a threshold `velocity.y > 0.01` due to rounding error.s*

---

Another approach could be to place an `Area2D` (or `RayCast2D`) child of the `KinematicBody2D` and use that to find out on what the player is standing up on.

Comment: the problem I found was with the alignment of the sprites so upon grouping the selected nodes and adjusting the white pointer in both sprite same the problem was solved your first method strucked my head with this idea so thank you!